# How to send an email from UIWebView in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, email, uiwebview

I have a mailto: link in UIWebView, but when I tap it nothing happens,

How can I open email editor?
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tried in this moment with mobile safari on my iPhone and when I tap on a mailto: link it open email composer. 
Are you trying to do this in iPhone simulator?
If not, have you configured an email account on you iPhone?

Comment: Yes, you are right, it works by default on iPhone and doesn't work in simulator